# Where does the "field" parameter come from?

Tags: c

I am working on a hardware RTL simulation project. I want to know some configuration bits positions from an exist firmware with C. However, I cannot understand some syntax. The code is in a head file and I don't understand where do the "*field" and "val" come from.

```
#define __BITFIELD(__type, __name, __bit, __width)                 \

static inline __type __name(volatile const void *field)             \

{                                                                   \

    volatile const __type *ptr = field;                             \

    return (*ptr >> (__bit)) & __BIT_MASK(__type, __width);         \

}                                                                   \

static inline void __name##_set(volatile void *field, __type val)   \

{                                                                   \

    volatile __type *ptr = field;                                   \

    *ptr &= ~(__BIT_MASK(__type, __width) << (__bit));              \

    *ptr |= (val & __BIT_MASK(__type, __width)) << (__bit);         \
}
```

Comment: Without context, I believe we know less then you do. Where does this code come from? The identifier "field` comes from function arguments `__name(volatile const void *field)` and this is a macro to define two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`field` and  `val` are arguments. They come from the signature of the function, so they literally are whatever you pass into the function. They come from you...

Answer (score -1):

I think you're confused by the fact that `__type`, `__name`, `__bit`, and `__width` come from the first line (that starts with `#define`) and looks like a function declaration, but `field` and `val` are not.

`__BITFIELD(...)` is not a function declaration, but a [C preprocessor (CPP) macro](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor_directives_and_macros##define) definition named `__BITFIELD`.

After this macro has been define, you can write something like this:

```
__BITFIELD(uint16_t, enable_counter, 4, 1)
```

The CPP will then expand that macro into "real" C code, replacing the macro arguments by what is literally entered above:

```
static inline uint16_t enable_counter(volatile const void *field)
{
    volatile const uint16_t *ptr = field;
    return (*ptr >> (4)) & __BIT_MASK(uint16_t, 1);
}  

...
```

This code will then be compiled.

So you'll end up with a function that has a `field` parameter.